# How do I move my button into a different location using the code I have? I have a simple GUI with awt and swing with a couple of classes

Tags: java, swing, awt, layout-manager, gridbaglayout

I'm trying to move my button into a different location within my simple, integrated GUI program. I believe.. that I have to do setLayout under the Pane class; but don't know whether or not my gridBagLayout object needs to be used. And what types of parameters/methods under those circumstances I should be using, I don't know.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TweetProgram1{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TweetProgram1();
    }

    public TweetProgram1() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Tweet Program");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TweetProgram1Pane());
                frame.setSize(500, 500);
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TweetProgram1Pane extends JPanel {

        public TweetProgram1Pane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());

            JLabel lbl = new JLabel("Random tweet");
            JButton btn = new JButton("Send it");

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = 300;
            gbc.gridheight = 300;
            add(lbl, gbc);
            add(btn, gbc);
        }

    }

}
```

Any tips or suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: at least read the documentation of [GridBagConstraints](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.desktop/java/awt/GridBagConstraints.html) or better some tutorial: [How to Use GridBagLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/gridbag.html)  (`gridwidth` is number of cells, not size, for example)

Comment: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: As I said the first time you asked this question:  we need more information on what type of move you want to accomplish.  Just stating “a different location” isn’t enough for anyone to recommend a particular layout or constraint.  You may also want to read [the LayoutManager tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/).

Comment: for *only*  two components you can use a simpler Layout, like for example a `BorderLayout` (instead of `GridBagLayout`). For simple dialogs, the `JOptionPare` is recommended: [JOptionPane Features](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features) -  it does not need any additional button, component or layout

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger thanks.